# how to get cryptojs to work with out "rollup" files

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I'm trying to upgrade the old version of cryptoJS that can be found [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/downloads) to a newer version on github that can be found [here](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/tree/develop/src) because, there are some functions on the old version that is going to be deprecated. Unfortunately, the newer don't have rollup files, so im trying to get it to work using the core files but, I keep getting the error(s) that something is "undefined" like "[cfg.hasher is undefined](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/crypto-js/0YBuugpJfNE)".

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="crypto-js3.1.9-1/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="crypto-js3.1.9-1/evpkdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="crypto-js3.1.9-1/x64-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="crypto-js3.1.9-1/cipher-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="crypto-js3.1.9-1/aes.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="crypto-js3.1.9-1/pbkdf2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="crypto-js3.1.9-1/hmac.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="crypto-js3.1.9-1/lib-typedarrays.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="crypto-js3.1.9-1/format-hex.js"></script>
```

I tried adding all the core files and even changing the orders of them, but I think I'm still missing something.

If I use the rollup files, this simple code below works just fine on it, but it fail on the newer version. Hopefully someone with more experience with cryptoJS can help me out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var string = "asdfasdfsadfdsa";
    var key = "asdfasfasfs";
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(string, key);
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key);
    alert(decrypted);
</script>
```

---

UPDATE!! I can get SHA256 to work just fine with out uses of require.js so I don't thing the problem is Modular include and the lib should be able to run "without RequireJS", but I'm still running into encryption and decryption error: "cfg.hasher is undefined".

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="CryptoJS/components/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="CryptoJS/components/sha256.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(CryptoJS.SHA256("Message"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do modular includes

Modular include using require js:

```
require.config({
    packages: [
        {
            name: 'crypto-js',
            location: 'path-to/bower_components/crypto-js',
            main: 'index'
        }
    ]
});

require(["crypto-js/aes", "crypto-js/sha256"], function (AES, SHA256) {
    console.log(SHA256("Message"));
});
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/janthony/b1cde9747d48c27b8e1c92ef461a8123) is a full gist

Comment: I'm confuse, am I adding this every time I encrypt and decrypt or at the start of the javascript file.

Comment: You do require.config() at the start only. But where you want to do encrypt/decrypt, you wrap it in the 
require(["crypto-js/aes", "crypto-js/sha256"], function (AES, SHA256) {
    console.log(SHA256("Message"));
});

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work, I even try the code above, but with different dir. "SHA256 is undefine".

Comment: Did you download a release zip?

Comment: yea, I'm using the zip version. dir: localhost/crypto-js. check the network tab in the dev and it found the file. need some sleep now, been at this all day. lol. thanks again. I'll check this again in the morning.

Comment: Here is my working page https://gist.github.com/janthony/b1cde9747d48c27b8e1c92ef461a8123