# How to use Crypto JS AES component with only core file and not rollup?

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I am using two Crypto JS functions: `CryptoJS.AES` and `CryptoJS.enc.utf8`. My code works perfectly fine when I use the aes.js rollup, however, the rollups are minified and I can only use unobfuscated files. Only the component file isn't minified (core.js and aes.js).

I have tried to use the solutions detailed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42523928/how-to-get-cryptojs-to-work-with-out-rollup-files). I used require, but I got errors in the AES component file and my code said that AES didn't exist. I have also tried using only the aes file, but that didn't work either. If anybody can find the AES rollup in an unobfuscated form, that would also be helpful.

[Here are the files for my CryptoJS version](https://github.com/sytelus/CryptoJS). Any help is appreciated, and  I will answer your questions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can use uglify to _format_ the code (not just minify). look for an online version.

Comment: @dandavis I tried that, but the variable names still remained short so the place where I'm submitting my code wouldn't accept it.

Comment: in that case, i would consider using the built-in AES; no code, faster, safer, more updated. i made a wrapper that makes it simple: https://github.com/rndme/aes4js